# Show part of query result

Tags: php, jquery, css, sql, joomla

I have such code in my template of joomla module:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 33px;" align="center"><strong>№</strong></td>
<td style="width: 148px;"><strong>Ник</strong></td>
<td style="width: 107px;"><strong>Рубли</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php

$position = 1;  

foreach ($top as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $position . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['0'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['1'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    $position ++;
}
?>
</table>
```

This code has shown a table with the result of JDatabaseQuery which contains in variable $top.

[result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okXBG.jpg)

I want to limit shown results in 10, add a button "show all" at the end, which will open result set of all list. I want to use jquery for that purpose.

What construct of css and jquery I should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using jquery, hide rows after 10 rows and on click of button show all rows -

```
$(function(){
    $("table tr:gt(10)").hide();
    //suppose below is the button on click of which you need to show all rows
    $("button").click(function(){
    $("table tr:gt(10)").show();
    });
});
```

See below code snippet

```js
$(function(){
  $("table tr:gt(10)").hide();
  $("#show").click(function(){
  $("table tr:gt(10)").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="show" type="button" value="Show Columns">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>HEADING1</th>
    <th>HEADING2</th>
    <th>HEADING3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column1</td>
    <td>column2</td>
    <td>column3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column1</td>
    <td>column2</td>
    <td>column3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column1</td>
    <td>column2</td>
    <td>column3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column1</td>
    <td>column2</td>
    <td>column3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column1</td>
    <td>column2</td>
    <td>column3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column1</td>
    <td>column2</td>
    <td>column3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column1</td>
    <td>column2</td>
    <td>column3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column1</td>
    <td>column2</td>
    <td>column3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column1</td>
    <td>column2</td>
    <td>column3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column1</td>
    <td>column2</td>
    <td>column3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column1</td>
    <td>column2</td>
    <td>column3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column1</td>
    <td>column2</td>
    <td>column3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column1</td>
    <td>column2</td>
    <td>column3</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>column1</td>
    <td>column2</td>
    <td>column3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column1</td>
    <td>column2</td>
    <td>column3</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>column1</td>
    <td>column2</td>
    <td>column3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column1</td>
    <td>column2</td>
    <td>column3</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>column1</td>
    <td>column2</td>
    <td>column3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column1</td>
    <td>column2</td>
    <td>column3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```